# How can I improve this regex for the last name?

Tags: regex

I learn about using regex in swift on raywenderlich, and they provide this regex for validating last names: `^[a-z'\\-]{2,20}$`. I know it works completely fine for some cases but when testing I notice that cases such as `Mc-----Corney` or `Hey'''''no` are validated as well.

I've tried to limit the usage of the apostrophe and the hyphen with **?** operator but it obviously doesn't work in bracket expressions. And one more problem is that I should have up to 20 characters whether or not I have **'** or **-** in the last name. Therefore I can move neither the apostrophe nor hyphen out of the bracket expression in order to achieve that (or most probably I just don't know how to do it properly yet).

So how can I modify that regex in order to only validate the last name that has from 2 to 20 characters in it and only one **'** **-** if any. I think it's a pretty silly question and there is an easy answer but since I just start learning regex I can't reach it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please keep in mind that not all problems can or should be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: Actually, regex knows nothing about parsing language constructs or names, etc.. Why you'd even try is a wonder .

Comment: Think about it in terms of what is required and what is optional. Every last name needs some number of consecutive letters, and names may optionally include a leading number of letters followed by a hyphen or apostrophe. You might choose to limit what things might be in front of an apostrophe, such as O'Smith.

Comment: `^(?=.{2,20}$)[a-z]+(?:['-][a-z]+)?$`

Comment: `Therefore I can move neither the apostrophe nor hyphen out of the bracket expression` <- wrong. `in order to achieve that (or most probably I just don't know how to do it properly yet).` <- true. When you decide, write down a set of rules, then we bake up a regex.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to validate human names you might want to have a read of this [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score -1):

`how can I modify that regex in order to only validate the last name that has from 2 to 20 characters in it and only one ' - if any`

A hyphen anywhere, but only 1 place,
can be done like this  :

`(?i)^(?=.{2,20})[a-z]*-?[a-z]*$`

A hyphen only after a letter has made an appearance , but only 1 place,
can be done like this  :

`(?i)^(?=.{2,20})[a-z]+-?[a-z]*$`

Comment: Not my vote but keep in mind that the OP also needs to allow an appropriate use of apostrophe (`'`) in the name.

Comment: Feel free to write your own ..,